# Wordpress : ACF image not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i try to display image but with Basic display (Object) but no showing

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($image);`?

Comment: @Rizier123 it's return 1 !

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you set as the return value

[image]

- Image Array will output as you have done
- Image URL will return a string of the URL
- Image ID will return the ID, so you'd need additional lookups to get the URL

**If you are using this outside a loop** then you must pass the [post ID](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) `get_field('image', $post_id);`

**If it is a taxonomy term and not a post/page** then you must [pass a prefix](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/) `get_field('image', 'category_' . $cat_id );`

Answer (score 0):

From the ACF docs:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

```html
<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): 

 // vars
 $url = $image['url'];
 $title = $image['title'];
 $alt = $image['alt'];
 $caption = $image['caption'];

 // thumbnail
 $size = 'thumbnail';
 $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
 $width = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];
 $height = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ];

 if( $caption ): ?>

  <div class="wp-caption">

 <?php endif; ?>

 <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>">

  <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" />

 </a>

 <?php if( $caption ): ?>

   <p class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo $caption; ?></p>

  </div>

 <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Using Object with the image field is more powerful, as it provides access to additional data, but requires a bit more work.

You may want to change the ACF field type to Image URL, which will return just the URL of the image, and can be inserted directly into your code

Hope this helps

D

Comment: when i use  `<?php $imageArray = get_field('image_field',$c);
var_dump($imageArray);
 ?>` it's return boolean(false)